# Spring cacheable - filter out empty collections using SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I wanted to know is there a way to use SpEL in order to filter out values like empty collections.

My cache currently filters out null values:

```
  @Cacheable(value = "groupIdToGroupNames",unless = "#result == null")
   public Map<Long, Collection<String>> findAllBySearchCustomerKey(final long groupId) {
    return idToNameClient.findAllGroupMembersById(groupId);
   }
```

I'm trying to find a way to filter out the groups that are of size 0 but not null.
Is there a way of doing that by using params for @Cacheable?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Something like this

```
unless = "#result==null or #result.size()==0"
```

More about [result](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-spel-context) and [or](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operators-logical).

Comment: I just added it. Newbe to SpEL:) Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

`unless = "#result==null or #result.isEmpty()"` works for me.

Comment: This does not seem to add anything new over the accepted 5 year old answer. It will probably be deleted by reviewers. If you think your answer makes a significant difference, you may want to add an explanation on how this is better than the existing answers.

Comment: probably this was more readable to me instead of #result.size()==0. Also agree with @nvoigt that we should add explanation over any answer.

Comment: adds plenty! a method `isEmpty` may end up doing something more than a simple check, and is worth it for readability as well

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an example (Artem Bilan answer is the valid one). My function can return Optional.ofEmpty or Optional of my object

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", unless = "#result == null", key = "@myDao.cacheKey(#id, #languageCode)")
public Optional<MyDTO> getMyStuff(int id, String languageCode) {
... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "recordCache", key = "#list", unless="#result == null or #result.size() == 0")
```